# Baryonic Tully Fisher Relation slope

Tags: galaxy

I'm studying the Baryonic Tully-Fisher relation. In the textbook I'm reading there is written that in order to construct this relation, one needs to derive a stellar mass, obtained for example by multiplying the galaxy luminosity by the stellar mass-to-light ratio, and add the mass of the gas. I don't understand a final consideration: the author says that, unlike for the Tully-Fisher Relation (luminosity vs velocity), where a change in the stellar mass-to-light ratio only affects the normalization of the relation, in the baryonic Tully-Fisher relation a different stellar mass-to-light ratio produces a different slope as well. Can anybody explain me this final consideration? Why does a change in the stellar mass to light ratio produce this change in the slope of the baryonic relation, and not only in the normalization?